# My fittonia plant is not healthy

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

I bought fittonia plant few weeks ago. I potted in soil, vermicompost and cocopeat mixture and keep it in semishade, also keeps the potting mix moist and mist the leaves twice a day. However few days ago the color of leaves started fading away and fell out of the plant, also some leaves tips have become brown and crispy and developed holes. What I am doing wrong? Can someone tell me?

Comment: Add a photo of your plant please..

Comment: Sounds like tipburn - either got too dry (even once), or too salty, or too much fertiliser.